# Controls added conditionally to a ASP.NET wizard step displayed as part of controls collection irrespective of the condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dynamic, wizard

I have a ASP.NET wizard step that includes a user control based on what was selected in a previous step:

```
        <asp:WizardStep ID ="WizardStep3" runat="server" Title="Step 3">
            <%switch (someFlag)
              {
                  case ("value a"):
            %>
                        <wizStep:Step3_ReportA ID="Step3_ReportA" runat="server" />
                        break;                                                        
                  case ("value b"):
            %>
                        <wizStep:Step3_ReportB ID="Step3_ReportB" runat="server" />
            <% 
                        break;
             } %>
        </asp:WizardStep>
```

*(Note: This is just pseudo markup so don't worry about the syntax)*

This approach seems to work okay and avoids the problems of adding controls dynamically to the page and all the persisting between postback headaches that brings.

However, I also have the following code that is used to validate what has been selected in the step:

```
protected void wizReportWizard_NextButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
{
    int stepId = e.CurrentStepIndex;
    var wizardStepControls = wizReportWizard.WizardSteps[stepId].Controls.OfType<BaseWizardStep>().ToList();

    foreach (var wizardStepControl in wizardStepControls)
    {
        if (wizardStepControl.IsStepValid())
        {
            wizardStepControl.DoSomething();
        }
        else
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

What I am finding confusing is that `wizardStepControls` contains **both step controls** (`Step3_ReportA` and `Step3_ReportB`) - **not just the control that has been included due to the `switch` statement**. Of course, when the page is rendered, only one control is output.

**So why do all controls in the switch statement get reported as belonging to the wizard step controls collection and how do I find which is the one that the switch statement has actually selected?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

someFlag seems to be a boolean and you are comparing on string...Moreover I cannot see any declaration of this "someFlag" variable , is it boolean? or is it a string??

Comment: Hi Muhammad. This is just pseudo code. The actually switch statement is much more complicated and based on an enumeration. Therefore, I don't believe this is a syntax issue as the page renders just fine.

Comment: Use instead 
Response.Write(@"<wizStep:Step3_ReportA ID="Step3_ReportA" runat="server" />");

Comment: That would just add the text "<wizStep:Step3_ReportA ID="Step3_ReportA" runat="server" />" into the output HTML, so wouldn't work. Anyway, thanks for your suggestions Muhammad, however I have now gone down the adding dynamic controls and just dealing with the assoicated headaches!

Comment: so would you like to share what was that you were missing?